# Частое падение "Mariadb/MySQL"

Tags: mysql

В последнее время часто падает mysql сервер не понятно из-за чего, хотя логично что из-за нехватки памяти, однако такое раньше не бывало. Вроде-бы сервер не нагружен, все как можно оптимизировано. Разве что смена OS на CentOS из Debian. Хотя на Debian еще ни разу не падал, точнее один раз, но после отключения InnoDB все было нормально. Подскажите, что увеличить в конфиге, что снизить? Какие действия предпринимать, чтобы mysql в конце концов не падал так часто. Буду очень благодарен тому, кто подскажет что делать в такой момент, как оптимизировать работу MySQL. Вот собственно последние логи mysql:

```
160814 15:29:02 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
160814 15:29:02 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.50-MariaDB) starting as process 610 ...
160814 15:29:02 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
160814 15:29:02 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)
160814 15:29:02 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)
160814 15:29:02 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 72499200 bytes)
160814 15:29:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160814 15:29:02 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160814 15:29:02 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160814 15:29:02 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.50-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
160814 15:29:04 [ERROR] mysqld: Table './database/table' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
160814 15:29:04 [Warning] Checking table:   './database/table'
```

**Конфигурационный файл my.cnf:**

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine=myisam skip-innodb 
local-infile=0
innodb_file_per_table = 1 
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
datadir=/var/lib/mysql 
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks symbolic-links=0 
query-cache-size = 8192 
thread-cache-size = 4 
[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log 
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid
```

Comment: Трудно что-то сказать без my.cnf и дополнительных сведений. Если не сложно покажите настройки и сообщите, что обслуживает сервер, как много соединений с ним устанавливается?

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Он не нужен, ибо у меня таблицы в MyISAM, думаю не из-за этого.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/blog/starting-mysql-low-memory-virtual-machines смотрел? если на сервере мало памяти... то перформанс_схема слишком много берет. кстати, про память и не написал в вопросе. Про innodb спросил потому, что уже лет шесть таблиц myisam не видел

Comment: Перформанс_схема у меня сейчас = FALSE стоит, значит отключен. Что касается памяти, оно если ты имеешь ввиду ОЗУ сервера 1ГБ. Но как выше написал для такого памяти нагрузка соответствующая я думаю.

Comment: А чем плох MyISAM? Чем лучше InnoDB?)

Comment: Нет, фреймворки не использую. Да и запросы вроде как оптимизированы. Использую mysqli. Дело в том, что когда у меня был Debian, то на нем ничего падал, но после установки CentOS то ли mysql всегда падает, то ли nginx и тому подобные странные ошибки как ни странно. Хотя глупо винить OS, но все же, получается так. Даже не знаю что делать. :(

Comment: свап проверь, он существует у тебя?

Comment: Вроде нет, ибо я не знаю что выполняет этот свап. Что это?

Comment: Раз выдает ошибку на старте, видимо дефолтные настройки кэшей требуют больше памяти, чем есть у сервера. Судя по маленькому конфигу, все значения стоят по умолчанию. Можно воспользоваться калькулятором http://www.mysqlcalculator.com/